# Specify function arguments from string

Tags: r, function

I'm trying to set up details for which function to run and which arguments to include at the start of my script, to then later call the function. I'm having trouble specifying arguments to be input into the function.
I have a fixed object

```
v <- c(1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,NA)
```

I want to specify which measurement function I will use as well as any relevant arguments.

Example 1:

```
chosenFunction <- mean
chosenArguments <- "trim = 0.1, na.rm = T"
```

Example 2:

```
chosenFunction <- median
chosenArguments <- "na.rm = F"
```

Then I want to be able to run this specified function

```
chosenFunction(v, chosenArguments)
```

Unfortunately, I can't just put in the string `chosenArguments` and expect the function to run. Is there any alternative way to specify the arguments to my function?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more the context in which you want to use `chosenFunction()` and `chosenArguments`? Are you putting it in an `lapply()` call or something? With a clearer context it's easier to find a solution.

Comment: I just want to specify the functions and arguments at the start because I reuse them multiple times in my script. If I want to change my measurement function, it's easier to change a few lines at the start that many lines throughout the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to calculate `mean`, we do it by

```
mean(v, na.rm = TRUE, time = 0.1)
#[1] 5.125
```

Another way is by using `do.call`

```
do.call(mean, list(v, na.rm = TRUE, trim = 0.1))
#[1] 5.125
```

We can leverage this fact and create a named list for `chosenArguments` and use it in `do.call`

```
chosenFunction <- mean
chosenArguments <- list(na.rm = TRUE, trim = 0.1)
do.call(chosenFunction, c(list(v), chosenArguments))
#[1] 5.125
```

Answer (score 2):

### Updated answer based on OP's clarifications

```
chosenFunction <- mean
get_summary <- function(x, fun, ...) fun(x, ...)> 
v <- 1:100 
get_summary(v, chosenFunction, na.rm = TRUE)
# [1] 50.5
```

Later on if you want to change the function

```
chosenFunction <- median
get_summary(v, chosenFunction, na.rm = TRUE)
# [1] 50.5
```

### Original answer

```
get_summary <- function(x, chosenFunction, ...) chosenFunction(x, ...)
v <- 1:100
get_summary(v, mean, na.rm = TRUE, trim = 1)
# [1] 50.5
get_summary(v, median, na.rm = TRUE)
# [1] 50.5
```

By doing `...`, you don't have to specify all arguments

```
get_summary(mean, na.rm = TRUE)
# [1] 50.5
```